# .NET6 not compatible with Visual Studio for Mac M1, what can I use for xamarin?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, apple-m1

I'm trying to learn how to make apps with xamarin forms. I'm using a M1 Macbook pro, and when I open Visual Studio, it says I have to uninstall my latest versions of .NET (I have .NET6), I read that .NET 3.1, 5, and 6 are not compatible with visual studio on Mac. I'm kind of new to Xamarin and using Visual Studio, so how can I make this app without the latest versions? Do I have to use .NET2? Does it still support cross-platform? I want to use xamarin, so is there a solution?

Comment: Who does say .net 6 is not in harmony with M1 series? You cannot use prior .net 6 with M1s, at least for now.

Comment: I may have misunderstood. But I think visual studio said it, but thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install Visual Studio 2022 for Mac preview

After it is done installing make sure to install the .NET6 workloads:

```
sudo dotnet workload install android
sudo dotnet workload install ios
```

That should be more or less it.

You can also use the maui-check tool as an alternative, just make sure you are running .NET6:

```
dotnet tool install -g Redth.Net.Maui.Check
maui-check
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was for Xamarin.Forms not MAUI. The only solution I have found to this is to install Visual Studio for Mac 2019 first, and then install 2022. Once you do this you can build and run Xamarin.Forms solutions in Visual Studio 2022